# Http 403 Error: Details Request had insufficient authentification scopes Google Classroom Announcements

Tags: google-classroom

I am using Python Google Classroom API to retrieve announcements data.
Here is my code.

```
from fetch import Fetch
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

cred = 'catp.json'
get_credits = Fetch(cred) #fetching credential data
credit = get_credits()

service = build('Classroom', 'v1', credentials=credit)
setup = service.courses()
data = setup.list().execute()['courses']
course_names = []
course_ids = []
for i in range(len(data)):
      course_names.append(data[i]['name'])
      course_ids.append(data[i]['id'])

announcement_data = setup.announcements().list(courseId=course_ids[0]).execute()
```

But I receive the following Traceback Error:
[image: Traceback Error]

Additional Information:
My project is registered under service account.
My role is Owner.
I have students account on Google Classroom.

To check  whether the same error would be called if I tried to access announcements from a teachers account I created a Course in Classroom, using my Students account and posted some demo announcements.
The result was the same TracebackError. I also tried getting access to the data using API Explorer from Google, passing the same course ID as an argument. The data was received normally without any errors.

[Edit]
Here is the code for fetching credentials, Fetch(cred):

```
import os
import pickle
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

class Fetch:
      def __init__ (self, credential_filename):
            self.scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.courses.readonly',
                           'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.announcements',
                           ]
            self.path = 'C:/frank/programs/python/google api'
            self.credential_file = credential_filename

      def __call__(self):
            os.chdir(self.path)

         
            token = open('token.pickle', 'rb')
            creds = pickle.load(token)

            if creds.valid == False:
                  if creds.expired == True:
                        creds.refresh(Request())
                  else:
                        try:
                              flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(self.credential_file, self.scopes)
                              creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
                        except FileNotFoundError:
                              print(f'{self.credential_file} does not exist')

                        token = open(self.token_file, 'wb')
                        pickle.dump(creds, token)
            return creds
```

Comment: Please provide the code related to `Fetch(cred)`. Most likely you are not providing the appropriate scopes, as the error says. Should be one of these at least: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.announcements`, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.announcements.readonly`. Also, I'm not sure you can use a service account to access this API (if not impersonating anyone), but first things first.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. If I use these scopes I can call `announcements: list` successfully. What I'm thinking is that you might have changed the scopes after creating the file `token.pickle` in which case any further scope change is not detected. In order to make sure that's the case, please remove the file `token.pickle` and try authenticating again.

Comment: Also, for the authentication process I didn't use your exact code `def Fetch` but the one coming from the [Python quickstart](https://developers.google.com/classroom/quickstart/python) since yours was causing extra errors (it fails when `token.pickle` doesn't exist for example). Be careful with that.